# Mapping Objects to 2D array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public class Item {
  public int id;
  public int price, stock;
  public Item(int id, int price, int stock) {
    id = this.id;
    price = this.price;
    stock = this.stock;
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  Item first = new Item(1, 23, 2);
  Item second = new Item(2, 345, 5);
  
  var myArray = new Array[50,50];
  myArray[0,1] = first;
  myarray[0,2] = second;
}
```

How can I map my Item object into my 2d array? Cannot implicitly convert type 'csharp.Program.Item' to 'System.Array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var myArray = new Array[50,50];
```

use

```
var myArray = new Item[50, 50];
```

This will create an Item array that lets you map values to the array without any conversion.

Comment: Thank you, i knew i missed something!